# What is the most convenient way to store a mesh?

Tags: 3d, mesh

On the process of implementing a toy 3D renderer, I'm questioning which format I could use to store my meshes. The possibilities are endless, an obvious one being those big flat arrays:

```
vertex_positions = [X,Y,Z, X,Y,Z, ...]
vertex_colors = [R,G,B, R,G,B, ...]
faces = [A,B,C, A,B,C, ...]
```

Question is: is there any particular recommendation for the format I am supposed to use, with some particular reason (IE: easy integration with other tools later on?), or is anything I do good enough?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" way to store the mesh.

It all depends on what you want to do with that mesh and how your algorithms need to access it. Depending on what you are doing each approach will have advantages and disadvantages.

Work out what you need to do and the "best" way (for you in this particular case) should become clear.